# Api Platform - Build in production failed : nuxt not found

Tags: nuxtjs3, api-platform.com

I use API Platform 3.2.

I'm deploying my API Platform application with Nuxt, and when I run the command:

`SERVER_NAME=your-domain-name.example.com \ APP_SECRET=ChangeMe \ POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ChangeMe \ CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET=ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey \ docker compose -f compose.yaml -f compose.prod.yaml up --wait`

I have the following error:

```
ERROR [pwa builder 4/4] RUN PNPM install --frozen-lockfile --offline --prod &&  pnpm run build                                                                                                     4.9s

> [pwa builder 4/4] RUN        PNPM install --frozen-lockfile --offline --prod &&      pnpm run build: 
> 3.272 ? The modules directory at "/srv/app/node_modules" will be removed and reinstalled from scratch. Proceed? (Y/n) ‣ true  
> 4.190 > nuxt-app@ build /srv/app  
> 4.190 > nuxt build  
> 4.190  
> 4.196 sh: 1: nuxt: not found
> `4.199  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.

------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --offline --prod && \tpnpm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Here is my pwa/Dockerfile:

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

# Versions

FROM node:lts AS node_upstream

# Base stage for dev and build

FROM node_upstream AS base

WORKDIR /srv/app

RUN corepack enable && \
corepack prepare --activate pnpm@latest && \
pnpm config -g set store-dir /.pnpm-store

# Development image

FROM base as dev

EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost

CMD ["sh", "-c", "pnpm install; pnpm dev"]

FROM base AS builder

COPY --link pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm fetch --prod

COPY --link . .

RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --offline --prod && \
pnpm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run nuxt

FROM node_upstream AS prod

WORKDIR /srv/app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs; \
adduser --system --uid 1001 nuxt

COPY --from=builder --link /srv/app/public ./public

USER nuxt

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And my compose.prod.yaml:

```
# Production environment override
services:
php:
build:
context: ./api
target: frankenphp_prod
environment:
APP_SECRET: ${APP_SECRET}
MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET}
MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET}

pwa:
build:
context: ./pwa
target: prod

database:
environment:
MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

This is the first time I've deployed API platform in production and I don't know where it could be coming from... Thanks for your help

I tried to do a pnpm install directly in pwa but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the line `COPY --from=builder --link /srv/app/public ./public` in my `pwa/Dockerfile` to `COPY --from=builder /srv/app/.output ./.output` and adding `COPY --link package*.json ./` before `pnpm install`. I also had to separate `pnpm install` from `RUN pnpm run build` and place `COPY --link . .` between the two.

Finally, I replaced `CMD ["node", "server.js"]` with `CMD ["node", ".output/server/index.mjs" ]` at the end of the file.

Here's my final file :

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

# Versions
FROM node:lts AS node_upstream

# Base stage for dev and build
FROM node_upstream AS base

WORKDIR /srv/app

RUN corepack enable && \
    corepack prepare --activate pnpm@latest && \
    pnpm config -g set store-dir /.pnpm-store

# Development image
FROM base as dev

EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost

CMD ["sh", "-c", "pnpm install; pnpm dev"]

FROM base AS builder

COPY --link pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm fetch --prod

COPY --link package*.json ./

RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --offline --prod

COPY --link . .
RUN pnpm run build
RUN pnpm prune

# Production image, copy all the files and run nuxt
FROM node_upstream AS prod

WORKDIR /srv/app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs; \
    adduser --system --uid 1001 nuxt

COPY --from=builder /srv/app/.output ./.output

USER nuxt

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOST localhost

CMD [ "node", ".output/server/index.mjs" ]
```

Hope this helps!